# Highlight partially matching text in Column A of Sheet 1, comparing with list in Column A of Sheet 2

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list email addresses in column A of Sheet 1. I also have a list of identifiers (identifying parts of an email address) in Column A of Sheet 2. 
For example for "myemail@gmail.com" in Sheet 1, I have "myemail" in Sheet 2.

I am looking for some code that compares the list in Sheet 1 with that in Sheet 2 and highlights the cells in Sheet 1 that contain the identifier in Sheet 2. How can I manage that?

Comment: You could look into conditional formatting, match and vlookup.

Comment: I have tried vlookup, but that works best for exact matches.  I have read up on match, but it doesn't seem to be the right way to go. I will experiment with conditional formatting, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use conditional formatting. 
Set it up to change the color of your first column if it matches a formula, then use something like this...
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A1)),"TRUE","FALSE")